# Runtime error 1004 (Excel file not opening)

Tags: excel, vba

I have an Excel file with a filename

```
CONSULT CHECKING SYSTEM (2.0L TURBO GASOLINE ENGINE)
```

When I try to open using vba code, this file it is not accepting decimal characters (2.0). When I removed decimal characters it is opening perfectly. How to make it accept decimal characters?

This is the code I am using to try to open the file:

```
"C:\Users\karthi\Desktop\New folder (2)" & "\" & Cells(i, 1).Value
```

`cells(i,1).value` will have `CONSULT CHECKING SYSTEM (2.0L TURBO GASOLINE ENGINE)`

Why is it not accepting decimal number?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add to the file name its "extension", too:

```
Workbooks.Open"C:\Users\karthi\Desktop\New folder (2)" & "\" & Cells(i, 1).Value & ".xlsx")
```